# How to give a time delay for a function call in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to give it some delay before calling the redirect URL in order to allow to store the needed data.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function?

Comment: Post some code of what you've got so far and what you have tried.

Comment: You're not trying to solve the problem, you're trying to work around it. The proper solution is to wait with redirecting exactly until you did what you have to do beforehand.

Comment: Structured question a bit, re-phrased it for better understanding. Feel free to edit it again in case I changed the original meaning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple solution is to use Router Service to redirect and setTimeout function for delay

```
    gotToPage() : void {
      // something
        setTimeout(() => this._router.navigateByUrl('url'),2500); // 2500 is millisecond
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well with Angular Version 13 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have such decorator in the [utils-decorators](https://vlio20.github.io/utils-decorators/#delay) (`npm install --save utils-decorators`) lib:

```
import {delay} from 'utils-decorators';

class SomeComponent {

   @delay(1000)
   func(): any {
    ....
   }
}
```

You will find other very useful decorators there, such as debounce, throttle and many more.

https://vlio20.github.io/utils-decorators/#delay